# How to get one button's hyperlink inside message via Gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

I am try to get one button's hyperlink inside message of gmail. Is there any way to make it via Google API? I tried the get message API, but it doesn't contain what i want.
The API i tried https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it

Thanks

Comment: Using get method, you will `get` the email's body as html (using a full format for example) and then you can parse it using any html parser lib to get the specific part of the html you want.

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by *get one button's hyperlink inside message of gmail*? A button from where? Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for you attention.

Comment: The button is a part of email content, you could image you receive one email to 'Reset' your password. So there is one link (<a href = ''https://app.link" >) embedded with the 'Reset' button. So what i want is get the link.

Comment: Thanks @BassemAkl, what i get is some content in json format, but not html, it doesn't contain what i need. Below is part of email content i got via the Get API:
},
   {
    "partId": "3",
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "filename": "get-started-button-1.0.png",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Disposition",
      "value": "inline; filename=\"get-started-button-1.0.png\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-ID",
      "value": "<get-started-image>"
     }

Comment: @AbelZhang, which format did you use? You should use `setFormat("full")` to get the whole content of message body as html.

Comment: @BassemAkl I used the format "full". But the the returned message isn't html format.